# What is the use of NSMakeRange in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I am new in Objective-C and have been using `NSRange` most of the time in my code.

I have just came to know that there is `NSMakeRange`. So, I just want to know - what is the use of `NSMakeRange`?

Comment: just FYI - you should google the questions like this if you don't want to be downvoted..

Answer (score 5):

It's a convenience *inline* function, used to create an `NSRange` `struct`, populate it and return it:

<sub>(from `.../Foundation.framework/Headers/NSRange.h`)</sub>

```
NS_INLINE NSRange NSMakeRange(NSUInteger loc, NSUInteger len) {
    NSRange r;
    r.location = loc;
    r.length = len;
    return r;
}
```

It makes it simpler to create ranges; compare:

```
unichar buffer[8];
[someString getCharacters:buffer range:NSMakeRange(2, 8)];
```

to:

```
unichar buffer[8];
NSRange range = { 2, 8 };
[someString getCharacters:buffer range:range];
```

Answer (score 3):

It's just a convenience function. It allows you to replace this:

```
NSRange r;
r.location = 1;
r.length = 2;
DoSomething(r);
```

with this:

```
DoSomething(NSMakeRange(1, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSMakeRange(5, 1)` creates a range with location 5 and length 1. See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSMakeRange) for further information and related functions.

Alt-click the function name in Xcode, you’ll get a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's to make range with specified two values. Some of the Objective-C APIs will require you to use this.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html):

> A structure used to describe a portion of a series—such as characters
>   in a string or objects in an NSArray object.

```
typedef struct _NSRange {
      NSUInteger location;
      NSUInteger length; } NSRange;
```

There are many ways of creating a NSRange object,

1 - using NSMakeRange

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(10, 50);
```

2 - By specifying within {}

```
NSRange range = {10,50};
```

3 - By properties

```
NSRange range;
range.location = 10;
range.length = 50;
```

Using either won't make much difference, but using `NSMakeRange` will definitely make your code more readable.